# Reading Data from a File as it grows

Tags: c#

I have a binary data file that is written to from a live data stream, so it keeps on growing as stream comes. In the meanwhile, I need to open it at the same time in read-only mode to display data on my application (time series chart).
 Opening the whole file takes a few minutes as it is pretty large (a few 100' MBytes). 
What I would like to do is, rather than re-opening/reading the whole file every x seconds, read only the last data that was added to the file and append it to the data that was already read.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using **FileSystemWatcher** to be notified of changes to the file. From there, cache information such as the size of the file between events and add some logic to only respond to full lines, etc. You can use the Seek() method of the FileStream class to jump to a particular point in the file and read only from there. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the writing of this file, I would split it in several files of a predefined size.

When the writer determines that the current file is larger than, say, 50MB, close it and immediately create a new file to write data to. The process writing this data should always know the *current* file to write received data to.

The reader thread/process would read all these files in order, jumping to the next file when the current file was read completely.

Comment: Interesting approach but this sounds too much trouble for the need. It is preferable to adapt to the problem rather than changing its wording

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor for changes in the file, like the example given here: [Reading changes in a file in real-time using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86534/reading-changes-in-a-file-in-real-time-using-net).

But I'd suggest that you evaluate another solution, including a queue, like RabbitMQ, or Redis - any queue that has Subscriber-Publisher model. Then you'll just push the live data into the queue, and will have 2 different listeners(subscribers) - one to save in the file, and the other to process the last-appended data. This way you can achieve more flexibility with distributing load of the application.